# How to find and then delete XML nodes with C#

Tags: c#, xml

I know C# but have not worked with anything XML before. I need to delete some nodes from a XML file. Below, the content of the file is shown partially.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:oxml="http://www.idontk.now/cove/ws/oxml/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.blahblah.org/wss/2001/02/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>HJNVB</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.beatles.com/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">AMts</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <oxml:solicitarRecibirCoveServicio>
            <oxml:comprobantes>
                <oxml:tipoOperacion>1234</oxml:tipoOperacion>
                <oxml:patenteAduanal>1234</oxml:patenteAduanal>
                <oxml:fechaExpedicion>2019-03-19</oxml:fechaExpedicion>
                <oxml:rfcConsulta>BEATLES1234</oxml:rfcConsulta>
                <oxml:tipoFigura>1</oxml:tipoFigura>
                <oxml:correoElectronico>undis@closed.nah</oxml:correoElectronico>
                <oxml:firmaElectronica>
                    <oxml:certificado>AugAw</oxml:certificado>
                    <oxml:cadenaOriginal>|1234|</oxml:cadenaOriginal>
                    <oxml:firma>12341234</oxml:firma>
                </oxml:firmaElectronica>
```

I need to find and then delete the **oxml:certificado** node, located inside the **oxml:firmaElectronica** node which is the last node shown on my sample XML code.

I am trying to find the **oxml:certificado** node with this C# code:

```
XmlNode certificado = doc.SelectSingleNode("/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/oxml:solicitarRecibirCoveServicio/oxml:comprobantes/oxml:firmaElectronica/oxml:certificado");
```

But I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XPath.XPathException'
>   occurred in System.Xml.dll Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed.
>   This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.

Any help on finding and deleting this node would be great. Thanks.